# Ruby syntax for declaring an lvalue / rvalue = operator

Tags: ruby

I am trying to build an equals function in Ruby.  What I want to do is something like this, suppose we have a class called A:

```
class A
    attr_accessor :secret_datum

    def public_datum
        return secret_datum
    end

    def public_datum= what
      secret_datum = what
    end
end
```

What I want basically is to build a more complex behind the scenes functionality depending on whether public_datum is used as an lvalue or an rvalue, but my code above does not work:

```
2.5.0 :027 > a = A.new
 => #<A:0x00007fc2293ec338> 
2.5.0 :028 > a.public_datum = 7
 => 7 
2.5.0 :029 > a.public_datum
 => nil
```

What is the correct syntax for declaring such a set of functions?

Comment: Maybe `secret_datum = what` should be `@secret_datum = what`? Look for instance and class variables.

Comment: "whether public_datum is used as an lvalue or an rvalue" - you meant `secret_datum` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When assigning a value to a bareword with `secret_datum = what`, you are **always** setting a simple local variable.

It seems that you actually want to use the setter of your class (which then sets the instance variable). For that, you have to hint to Ruby that you want to call the method. You can do this by defining a receiver object. Your setter can thus look like this:

```
def public_datum=(what)
  self.secret_datum = what
end
```

Alternatively, you could directly set the instance variable as follows:

```
def public_datum=(what)
  @secret_datum = what
end
```

As a final note, please be aware that your `secret_datum` accessor is still public. Thus, you could also call `a.secret_datum = 7` and it would work exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

An instance variable is declared with a prepended "@" like
    @secret_datum = what

Without the @ the variable is declared on the stack and gone when you exit the function.

So just refer to the instance variable as @secret_datum and it will work

```
def public_datum=(what)
  @secret_datum = what
end
```

Comment: Ah, but it looks like he specifically wanted to use the method